# C++ Suspected stack overflow changing function parameters

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am working on implementing a user level thread library in C++ using `setcontext()`, `makecontext()`, `getcontext()`, and `swapcontext()` on a Linux system.

I am using a wrapper function to wrap the function the user wants to run as a thread. For example, the user calls `newthread(funcPtr)`, and within the thread library `funcPtr` is passed to a wrapper function that runs it.

The error occurs differently depending on whether or not I initiate an unused string within the function. If I include the line `string s = "a";` the program will run to completion, but `gdb` reveals that context is switching to somewhere within the string library. Without this line, the program segfaults after leaving the function wrapper.

The `gdb` output shows the corruption of the parameters to `function()`.

I ran `valgrind` but did not see anything particularly out of the ordinary in the output, just many "Invalid read of size 4" and "Invalid write of size 4" warnings, usually within the C++ standard `map`.

Comment: For starters, post some code. This is probably stack-related.

Comment: If adding or removing a variable stops a segfault then that is a good indication of stack corruption.

Comment: Do not post *some code*, post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)!

Comment: Stack corruption/buffer overflow, not stack overflow - stack overflow is when you hit the top of the stack and the program dies immediately. Your program is still (kind of) alive. And like others have said, post the code that produces this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `invalid read` and `invalid write` are in fact "out of the ordinary" and you should first investigate why valgrind thinks you're reading and writing invalid memory.

Comment: You are using a lot of unnecessary allocations - for instance, in Semaphote, waitqueue should just be a queue<ucontext_t*>, rather than a pointer.  There is also no need to first malloc the Semaphore (and even if there was, you should use 'new' anyway), then assign to a local, then copy into a map. Make those changes and see if your valgrind errors go away.

Comment: One thing that could definitely be causing the errors is if you make the call 'semmap[sem].waitqueue->empty()' when you have not yet added a Semaphor with the key 'sem' yet.  In that case, 'semmap[sem] will construct a new Semaphor with an invalid pointer for waitqueue. Then, dereferencing it, you'll get undefined behavior, possibly including messing up your stack.

Comment: Any particular reason for `malloc(sizeof(Semaphore))` (etc.) instead of the bog standard `new Semaphore()`?

Answer (score 3):

You could try also [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki) for debugging. It can detect stack buffer overflows.  Here's how to use it on Linux:

At least gcc 4.8 is needed for AddressSanitizer and libasan must be installed (e.g. on Fedora `yum install libasan` as root). Compile and link with `-g -fsanitize=address` and run the generated executable. AddressSanitizer stops and emits information if it detects the first error, no long log files have to be analyzed. Solve the reported problem, compile and run again until AddressSanitizer doesn't stop the program anymore. Unfortunately there might be false positives because you use swapcontext in your program, but it's worth a try. Instrumentation can be turned off for a specific function by adding the attribute no_sanitize_address: `extern int func(void) __attribute__((no_sanitize_address));`

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane Please use upvotes to indicate good and useful posts, not to circumvent site rules. If you think the 50 Rep rule is bad, complain about it on Meta. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) is an explanation on that.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I would not have upvoted if I didn't think it was useful.

Comment: @WeatherVane: that's not a reason to upvote. It's not hard to get `50` reputation. Asking two good questions or answer a question you know the answer is in many cases sufficient.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @CommuSoft OP did not have a question but said *"I have been struggling with this for days an am at a complete loss. Any help is greatly appreciated"*. So how is this not a useful answer?

Comment: @WeatherVane: for two reasons: (a) it's not an answer to the question: the answer doesn't solve the problem. Indeed the link can be useful, but it does not provide a canonical answer; and (b) this should - according to the SO rules - be a comment. But I agree that the reputation threshold is problematic. Didn't downvote it...