# Malloc assertion

Tags: c, unix, malloc

I'm using `malloc()` in a function.
First call of the function works fine but the second time, I got

```
allum1: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Abandon (core dumped)
```

Why ?

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to know if you don't post the code.

Comment: Looks like the code run before somehow smashed the memory management. However without the source there is no reliable diagnosis possible.

Comment: Sorry, code is here : http://pastebin.com/VTtM2vgX

Comment: Edit the post to include your code, don't link to external resources.

Comment: Code is a bit longer...

Comment: You are expected to trim it down to smallest instance reproducing the same behaviour. That is, start by removing extra parts until you hit approx. 10 lines exhibiting the same behaviour. In the process you might discover and fix the bug by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you have a memory corruption somewhere in your code (for example, writing though a dangling pointer, or writing past the end of an array).

If you can't find the bug by reading the code, try using an automated tool such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: I can't use Valgrind because the function that cause this bug wait for a user-entered input...

Comment: @user3486006: Valgrind does not block user input.

Comment: @user3486006: I don't quite follow how that prevents the use of Valgrind. Besides, you can always redirect the input from a file (which might also make the test more repeatable).

Comment: Ok thanks, when crashing I got http://pastebin.com/ec4gYaQP

Comment: @user3486006: The interessting things are shown by Valgrind (long?) before the crash.

Comment: So what i'm supposed to do ?

Comment: You could try also AddressSanitizer beside Valgrind. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28571060/4566976) for brief instructions.